# Discord.py obtaining user ID from username

Tags: discord.py

I have a discord.py code that needs to transfrom a username (example: duviz#0) to a user id.
How can I do that? I searched on google but I didn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the solution:

```
user = discord.utils.get(bot.users, name=USERNAME)
```

Comment: And by the way you have to delete the #0 if you don't have a discriminator